# Java: split text

Tags: java, brackets

I need to split a text (String), the text is just like this:

```
[title],[description blablablablablabla]
```

Is there a way to do this? I need to store in a String[] the 2 texts between brackets, separated by a ",".

Comment: String split function. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: [`string.split(",")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: @jrowe08 That documentation is very out of date. Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String- instead.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Considering that it was released a week ago, chances are they're not using Java 8.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat ...It's the same exact documentation for the method, just with a different font.

Comment: i wonder why you posted this question here, as you know the answer clearly "Java: split text" . Had you googled, you would have got it directly from the docs.

Comment: Can the text in the brackets contain a `","`? Can the text in brackets contain brackets, escaped somehow? E.g., `"[one \[two\] three]"`?

Comment: Yes, the text can have a ",". That´s my problem...i was using the String.split() as many of you have answered me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
String input = "[title],[description blablablablablabla]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

while(matcher.find()) {
    stringList.add(matcher.group(1));
}

//If you just need the results to be stored in an array of Strings anyway.
String[] stringArray = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
```

Comment: This code really helped me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `split(String str)` method of class String. Example:

```
String resultArray[] = stringToSplit.split(",");
```

Comment: How will this work if the `[title],[description]` is `"[Hans Brinker, or The Silver Skates],[A colorful portrait of early nineteenth-century Dutch life, as well as a tale of youthful honor.]"`?

Comment: That is exactly my doubt. Inside a bracket could have a ",".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is quite easy, try this :

```
    String text = "[title],[description blablablablablabla]";        
    String[] splitted = text.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");
```

Comment: just fyi, when the replacement term doesn't need to be regex (as here), you can simply code `text.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");`. Or you could use a regex, but combine the two replacements into one call: `text.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").split(",");`. Less code == good :)

Answer (score 1):

To split string you can use this method:

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

Or

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

For more details visit http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Example:

```
String a = "Hi guys, what's up?"
String[] b = a.split(",");
```